# Prevent Stringifcation of Objects Passed Into Eval

Tags: javascript, eval

Consider this code:

```
function set(n,v) {  // This is a setter
    eval(n+"="+v);
}

let one = 1;
function add1(num) {
    return num + one;
}

{
    let two = 2;
    set("add1", function(num) {
        return num + two;
    });

}

// Add 1 now equals: 
//  function(num) {
//      return num + two;
//  }

// So if we call add 1:
add1();

// We get a "Uncaught ReferenceError: two is not defined"
```

This is because `eval` stringifies the function which removes its connection to variables it counts on

How do I stop this (keep the `set` behavior, but prevent the function from leaving behind variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DON'T USE `eval` for variable variables. Use objects instead, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5187652/8376184)**

Now, to answer your question: as a *direct* `eval` can access your local variables, all you have to do is read them inside the `eval` string, instead of passing from the outside:

```
function set(n, v) {
    eval(n + "= v");
}
```